# Learning Embedded Systems Programming Using ARM Microcontrollers

Tags: embedded, arm

I have just joined a project which require working on ARM based micro-controllers.. i have been a web developer for sometime and i am in need of some materials and resources to startup with embedded systems on ARM Micro-controllers. I am absolute newbie in this field so please provide me some online resources / tutorials / ebooks to brushup the basics.

Microcontroller We are using:

AT91 ARM
Thumb
Microcontrollers
AT91SAM9R64
AT91SAM9RL64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with familiarization with ARM9 architecture. There is a lot of articles/online guides available on ARM site in documentation section. After that, it depends on how deep you want to go, there is a [list of book](http://www.arm.com/support/resources/arm-books/index.php) on ARM site which can be used as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM ARM (ARM Architecture Reference Manual) is a must have.  And because there are no so many variants, ARM also publishes (also a free download) a TRM (Technical Reference Manual) for the specific core in your device.  so go to atmel and their documentation will indicate specifically which ARM9 core, and then go to ARM's site and look that core up and get the TRM.  Atmel may choose to also provide copies of that TRM or set of TRMS.  Sometimes the cache is a separate TRM.  I think for those ARM9's though what you need is in a single TRM, plus general ARM basic knowledge from the ARM ARM.